# how to declare a pointer in C syntax?

Tags: c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C++ Pointer in Function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2367202/c-pointer-in-function)

Are are these statements the same in C when declaring a pointer?

```
 int *ptr;
 int * ptr;
 int* ptr;
```

Comment: closed as a duplicate of a question that was already closed as a duplicate?  Nice.

Comment: Skipping reading basic programming texts and instead going to Stack Overflow? Seriously?

Answer (score 1):

As noted in the linked question, they are all the same (just make sure to use one **consistently** - especially when working with existing codebase).

The only 2 differences are:

- The first format is what K&R uses. Many people default to K&R when talking about styling C code.
- `int* p, x;` is misleading, since x is int and not int*, so be aware of that pitfall when using the 3rd syntax.

Answer (score 1):

The three declarations are equivalent.

```
int *ptr;  // Kernighan & Ritchie style
int* ptr;  // Stroustrup style
```

Comment: Downvoter, please explain why you downvoted.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. It's mainly a matter of preference, though in my experience most people prefer either the first or third.

Personally, I prefer the first, because of a siutation like:

```
int *ptr1, *ptr1;
```

whereas

```
int* ptr1, ptr2; /* ptr2 is NOT a pointer, needs another * before it to be one */
```

EDIT:

To be clear, one is not more correct than the other and you should choose which one makes the most sense to you.  Above all, it's probably most important to use one consistently throughout your code.

Comment: Different styles can definitely lead to ambiguity and confusion about what happens, as well as what the author actually intended!

Comment: -1: What you said is not a reason to prefer that syntax. It's a reason to prefer single declarations

Comment: I disagree :) because reading from left to right with `int* ptr` you are saying that there's a pointer to integers called ptr, while with `int *ptr` you are saying that there's an integer, no wait, it's a pointer to an integer... that is I want to emphatize that pointer to int is a type. and I would discourage a multiple declaration in the same line :)

Comment: Sure. There are arguments to be made either way ;). I'm certainty not implying that one is more correct than the other. Probably the most important bit is to establish a style and be consistent throughout the whole code.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried? Yes they are. I for my part always prefer the first way. But I will not start a new "formatting" war here ;-(

Comment: You just did!!!  How can anyone go for `int *x`?  I've never understood it.  You're defining an `int*` named x, not an `int` named *x.  And the Qt IDE actually autocorrects towards the first version... <facepalm>