# Difference between datatype* <variable name> vs. datatype *<variable name>

Tags: c, pointers, struct, linked-list

I studying how to create linked lists in C. Take a look at [this article](http://geeksquiz.com/linked-list-set-1-introduction/).

First he creates the structure using the following code;

```
struct node 
{
  int data;
  struct node *next;
};
```

Its clear that *next is a pointer variable of the type node.

But when he goes forward, he does this;

```
struct node* head = NULL;
struct node* second = NULL;
struct node* third = NULL;
```

Now here I have a problem comprehending what he is trying to do; is he creating nodes of the names, head, second and third? or he is simply trying to create pointer variables of the type node?

Since he puts them equal to NULL; I'd assume he is trying to create pointer variables. But couldn't he do the same using this?

```
struct node *head = NULL;
struct node *second = NULL;
struct node *third = NULL;
```

Thanks

Comment: And what about the difference between `struct node  *head` and struct node `struct node    *head` ????

Comment: What is the difference between `a= a+b` and `a =a+b` ?

Comment: There is no difference whatsoever between `struct node* head` and `struct node * head` and `struct node *head` and `struct node                      *head`.

Comment: The two code blocks have the *exact* same meaning to the compiler.  It's a matter of taste which one to use.

Comment: SO is actually [full](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9280265/how-to-declare-a-pointer-in-c-syntax) [of](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2367202/c-pointer-in-function) [duplicates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12626929/pointer-c-declaration) of this question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In C, the whitespace before or after the `*` is meaningless. So:

```
struct node *head;
struct node * head;
struct node* head;
struct node*head;
```

are all exactly the same. C doesn't care about that whitespace.

Where you get into trouble is when you declare multiple items:

```
struct node *head, tail; // tail is not a pointer!
struct node *head, *tail; // both are pointers now
struct node * head, * tail; // both are still pointers; whitespace doesn't matter
```

Answer (score 1):

Both are the same technically.....

```
struct node *third = NULL;
struct node* third = NULL;
```

does the same thing as the compiler doesn't count the white spaces.